# Node JS file upload with AWS SDK | Error: Cannot determine length of [object Object]

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use the AWS SDK on my sails js app. I keep getting this error: Cannot determine length of [object Object]. Does anyone know whats causing this?

Here is the code:

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

```
              var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
                accessKeyId : 'xxx',
                secretAccessKey : 'xxx',
                params: {Bucket: 'sweetestspots'}
              });
              var body = req.file('cover');

              s3bucket.upload({Key: 'filename', ACL:'public-read', Body:body}, function(err, data) {
                console.log ("data")
                console.log (data)
                if (err) {
                  console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
                  return res.send("err");

                } else {
                  console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
                  console.log(data);

                  return res.send("uploaded");
                }
              });
```

Comment: may i know what is value of `body` that you are uploading ?

Comment: The body is req.file('cover') parsed from the front end which is an image.

Comment: Dont show your secret key.

Comment: thanks @arjunkori :D thats removed now

Comment: @steph - You have to change your keys. Editing this question isn't enough. People can see them in the history. Do it now.

Comment: Ok have done it. Thanks @AdrianLynch :)

Comment: This answer is relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43460803/1191551

Answer (score 4):

according to the [aws](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property)

the `Body` should have a value of **buffer, blob, or stream**

```
upload(params = {}, [options], [callback])
```

> Uploads an arbitrarily sized buffer, blob, or stream, using intelligent concurrent handling of parts if the payload is large enough. You can configure the concurrent queue size by setting options.

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream};
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err, data);
});
```

you need to stream your file like `fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)` and send put it in the `Body` parameter

Answer (score 2):

Hi i got the same problem,
i am sending you my code.

```
            var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
                accessKeyId: 'xxx',
                secretAccessKey: 'xxx+xxx',

            });


            var body = new Buffer(req.file('cover'), 'base64');

            var params = {
                Bucket: 'sweetestspots',
                Key: 'yourimagename',
                Body: body,
                ContentEncoding: 'base64',
                ContentType: 'image/png',
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };

            s3bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket" + JSON.stringify(data));

                }
            });
```

Please try this code.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I'm now getting an error about buffer. It says: TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by this line: 
var body = new Buffer(req.file('cover'), 'base64');

Comment: Don't paste your keys! (and I'd change them quick)

Comment: change it to var body = new Buffer(req.file.cover,'base64);'

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this kind of error. The problem is you need to pass `Body` as `Buffer`. I did it in this way and the issue was gone :

```
router.post("/upload-image", (req, res) => {
  let imageFileName;
  const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });

  busboy.on("file", (fieldName, file, fileName, encoding, mimetype) => {
    if (mimetype !== "image/jpeg" && mimetype !== "image/png") {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Bad format in the image" });
    }

    const filePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);

    const params = {
      Bucket: "your bucket name",
      Key: fileName,
      Body: "",
      ACL: "public-read",
      ContentType: mimetype,
    };


    file.on("data", function (data) {
      params.ContentLength = data.length;
      params.Body = data;
    });

    // needed to call upload function after a while, because params was not updating immediately 
    setTimeout(() => {
      s3.upload(params, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ imageURL: data.Location });
      });
    }, 1000);

    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
  });

  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
});
```

And this code will also solve for getting zero bytes after uploading an image to s3

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using putObject to upload a stream. The solution is either switch to upload or use a buffer/blob instead of a stream.